# SQL Get current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have table1 with data

```
file  Startdate
A     2020-05-01
B     2020-06-01
```

We have today is 2020-06-01 and I could use Select and where startdate ='2020-06-01'
But I try this query and not get 2020-06-01

```
select file from table1
where
 startdate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
         and startdate < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

Please correct me. Thank you

Comment: You want `<=` instead of `<`, I suppose.

Comment: Are you just looking for `SELECT [File] FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WHERE Clause to find all records in a specific month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851236/where-clause-to-find-all-records-in-a-specific-month)

Comment: Great. If I added a record with startdate  = '2020-06-02' then the query SELECT [File] FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) will pick 2 records for the month July?

Comment: Your current filter says "give me all the data for last month." If you want to include data from this month, you need to write a query that doesn't exclude data from this month. How do you expect `< '2020-06-01'` to return the value `'2020-06-01'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
select [file] from table1
where
 startdate = datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

This'll returns

```
file  Startdate
B     2020-06-01
```

---

UPDATE:

> I mean not just 2020-06-01 but if I add 2020-06-02 then should get 2 records for 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-02

```
SELECT [File]
FROM Table1
WHERE StartDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
      AND
      StartDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE());
```

Comment: so this query will pick any day of july month?

Comment: When we 're on July, it 'll pick only `2020-07-01`. Since we're not yet on July it 'll pick only `2020-06-01`

Comment: I mean not just 2020-06-01 but if I add  2020-06-02 then should get 2 records for 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-02

Comment: Aside: [`EoMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns a `Date`. If it is compared to a `DateTime` then any time past midnight at the start of the last day of the month tends to get ignored. A solution is to use `... and StartDate < DateAdd( day, 1, EoMonth( GetDate() ) );`. Note `<` rather than `<=` to accept all times up to, but not including, midnight at the start of the next month.

Answer (score -1):

datefromparts clutter it, it's much easier to write and understand it like this.
Mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(getdate(), "%Y-%m-01");
```

MSSql

```
SELECT CONVERT(NOW(), varchar(8),120) + '01'
```

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` is a MySQL function while the question tagged with SQL Server.

Comment: Fair enought, added a line for mssql  as well

Comment: @Griffin, I think you were looking for this... `SELECT cast(format(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') as Date)`

Comment: @SS_DBA well format is only supported from sql 2012 and forward, convert has been around forever. But thanks for updating me that format has been introduced, it's most wellcome.
Casting it as date might be a good idea for performance, but the engine will convert the text to date for you otherwise (not really sure if it has any impact in real world).

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table1 
where StartDate= cast(getdate() as date)
```