# Is there a way to search just month and day in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm looking to just select a certain month and date (12/25), but don't care about the year. I tried this

```
WHERE DAY(date) = 25 AND MONTH(date) = 12;
```

But that didn't work. Any way to just search month and day? The field is timestamp without time zone.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And "didn't" work is not helpful.  What is the issue.

Comment: is any error message displayed? if yes, can you please add that to your question?

Comment: Take a look for this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851236/where-clause-to-find-all-records-in-a-specific-month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851236/where-clause-to-find-all-records-in-a-specific-month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL standard syntax would be:

```
where extract(day from date) = 25 and
      extract(month from date) = 12
```

Most databases, however, support the `day()` and `month()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem. I tested using MySQL.

```
SELECT ... FROM Table t WHERE MONTH(name_column) = :month AND DAY(name_column) = :day
```